# Codelens ignores class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-6, codelens

Why might Codelens ignore a class?

This class shows the Codelens mark up " 1 reference"

[image]

This class does not

[image]

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding
I am using VS2017 with Resharper

both classes have a DbSet in the DbContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes due to cerculer references Codelens does not work properly.

This link https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/809868/codelens-not-displaying-references

may help you.

Thanks